# Can I have Linux on the same SSD as my Windows Games (dual boot)?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, games

I tried looking for a lot of similar questions but I really didn't get the answer I wanted, so that's why I'm asking here.

I have a Legion laptop for both college and gaming, and on my disk C: i have Windows, and on my disk D: it's the games I have installed. It's 1tb NVMe, but I have a lot of free space and I was thinking about doing a dual channel, so my question is, if I put linux on this disk D:, when I'm on windows, can I still play these games? Do they have any problem with the linux boot? I'm dual booting mostly to learn about dual booting and to use for coding.
If my question is poorly explained, I'm sorry, I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: yes with dual booting and grub. it's not trivial though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: You cannot install Ubuntu in "D: Drive" as that is a NTFS partition.  If just testing you can use WSL but dual boot requires Linux format partitions like ext4 to support ownership & permissions which is part of the reason Linux is more secure than Windows. Use Windows tools to shrink the largest NTFS partition to make unallocated space. Only use Something Else, so you manually add partition and make sure you have good backups.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 2):

You can install Ubuntu on D: if you use virtualization (virtualbox or vmware player). You can then use Windows and Ubuntu at the same time though these two will share your memory so you more memory is better (8Gb or more).

If you do want a dual boot you need to split D: into 2 parts and leave the 2nd part unallocated (so shrink D:) You can do that using a live [gparted](https://gparted.org/). During installation for pick "something else" and use the unallocated space to create a / mountpoit.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu in a dual boot requires editing the partitions of your D: drive to create a new partition for Ubuntu. Ubuntu does not use NFTS, so a new format of that new partition is required. You want that format to be of empty space, of course.

Follow the instructions for editing your Windows partition carefully. Don't take shortcuts. If you make a mistake, then your games and all other data on that partition may be deleted. Backups are wise.

The new ext4 format will also make the new partition unreadable and unwritable by Windows without an add-on.

You can avoid a lot of unnecessary work and risk by using a virtual machine instead of dual-booting. Then no partition edits or formatting is needed. Most dual-booters transitioned to VMs over a decade ago.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there shouldn't be any problem. Let's clarify some points:

1. In your case, you will have to look for a way to create a *Dual Boot* between your two disks. When you install Ubuntu in the same disk you have Windows, this will use the *EFI Boot Partition* that Windows created, but in this case you will have to do some setups to add the Windows Boot Entry in your *GRUB* when you already got Ubuntu installed in your second disk. You can look for this on the web.
2. No. There should be no problem with your games. This will be like when you install Ubuntu alongside Windows in the same disk: You left part of your second disk's space with no use, so you can create your Ubuntu new partitions, and them will not affect the partition where you have your games.

Go ahead, **just be sure that you are not going to touch the partition where you have your games**. Remember that you have two separated disks and within every disk you can create partitions that will not affect the other ones, and look for a guide about how to make a *Dual Boot* if you have Windows and Ubuntu in different disks.

Good luck! ^^/

Comment: There is no need for **bold** text, as long as you are creating (and verifying) a backup first.